# How can I read a file line by line for 10 seconds?

Tags: php, time, while-loop

I'm working on a project where I need to read a log and check for errors. I'm using a while loop like so:

```
 while($count < 10) { 
      $count++;
      # Stop waiting if an exception is thrown
      $sdata = file($logfile);
      $lastline = $sdata[count($sdata)-1];
      if(startsWith($lastline, "Running:") == false or startsWith($lastline,"Executing:") == false) { break; }
      sleep(1);  
 }
```

This is checking the log every second, however, I need to read EVERY line as it comes in. How do I read the last line of the log as it is written while maintaining a timeout value for the while loop?

Comment: Are you trying to watch the file for changes once per second for 10 seconds, or are you trying to poll the file as frequently as possible for 10 seconds?

Comment: I'm trying to poll the file as frequently as possible for 10 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
$time = time();
$stop = $time+10;
while($time < $stop) { 
    $time = time();
    # Stop waiting if an exception is thrown
    $sdata = file($logfile);

    $lastline = end($sdata);
    if(startsWith($lastline, "Running:") == false or startsWith($lastline,"Executing:") == false) { break; }

}
```

Comment: I removed the loop as you're only loking for the last line

Comment: Note that this approach doesn't guarantee that you'll process *every* line if your program can output faster than you can read a whole file in memory. The bigger the log file, the bigger the possibility of you missing a line.